# How to make this loop succesful after a succesful attempt?

Tags: python

The retry function tries to execute an operation that might fail, it retries the operation for a number of attempts. Currently the code will keep executing the function even if it succeeds. Modify the code so that it stops trying after the operation succeeded.

```
def retry(operation, attempts):
  for n in range(attempts):
    if operation():
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " succeeded")
    else:
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed")

retry(create_user, 3)
retry(stop_service, 5)
```

Comment: Is it an exam test?

Comment: Use `break` or `return` in `if block`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Early_exit_from_loops

Comment: use [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: it works for the first call but not for the second

Comment: If you don't care about the result of `operation`, `if any(operation() for _ in range(attempts))`

Answer (score 1):

Add a *break* to exit the loop when the *operation()* i successful:

```
def retry(operation, attempts):
  for n in range(attempts):
    if operation():
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " succeeded")
      break
    else:
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed")
```

Comment: FYI This is from Coursera's Python Crash Course. This would be my answer too. But the question is unclear. All that is allowed is to place a line of code where you placed `break`. However, something like `retry(stop_service, 5)` yields something like `Attempt 0 failed Attempt 1 failed Attempt 2 failed Attempt 3 succeeded Attempt 0 failed Attempt 1 failed Attempt 2 failed Attempt 3 succeeded None`, which clearly does not satisfy the question's requirements of "stopping after a success". I could fix this code by changing `for n in range(attempts)` to a `while` loop, but it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try break to exit from the loop if operation() is successful.

```
def retry(operation, attempts):
  for n in range(attempts):
    if operation():
     print("Attempt " + str(n) + " succeeded")
     break
    else:
     print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed")
retry(create_user, 3)
retry(stop_service, 5)
```

Your result should look like :

```
Attempt 0 failed
Attempt 1 failed
Attempt 2 succeeded
Attempt 0 succeeded
Attempt 0 failed
Attempt 1 failed
Attempt 2 failed  
Attempt 3 succeeded
None
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some issues with this question, the marked correct output for this question is:

Attempt 0 failed

Attempt 1 failed

Attempt 2 succeeded

Attempt 0 succeeded

Attempt 0 failed

Attempt 1 failed

Attempt 2 failed

Attempt 3 succeeded

None

There are two function calls, one with create_user and one with stop_service, however, even after the first two "succeeded" occurred, the program continues to go.

Comment: A very similar question appears in Coursera's Python Crash course, where it's clearly stated that only the line where `break` is placed is to be modified, with the result that you point out: a clear contradiction to the question's requirement. The way the OP stated the question would suggest changing the `for n in range(attempts)` to a `while` loop is permitted, but the Coursera quiz clearly rules it out. So to conclude: There are issues with the Coursera question and/or there are issues with the current top-voted answers here. Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

```
def retry(operation, attempts):
  for n in range(attempts):
    if operation():
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " succeeded")
      break # will stop the loop when or if this is line reached
    else:
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed")

retry(create_user, 3)
retry(stop_service, 5)
```

You should use `break` keyword to stop the loop when needed, or even `return` would be suitable in that situation.

[Python loop reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a try and except block

```
def retry(operation,attempts):
    for attempt in range(attempts):
         try:
             if operation():
                 operation()
                 print('Attempt '+str(attempt)+' succeded')
                 break
             else:continue
          except:
              continue

retry(create_user,4)
```

This will catch any exception if any was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` after the if before the `else`. There is a problem with the question (or it is misleading), but `break` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
def retry(operation, attempts):
  for n in range(attempts):
    if operation():
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " succeeded")
      break
    else:
      continue
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed")

retry(create_user, 3)
retry(stop_service, 5
```

Comment: This has been already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59955536/18145256).